# install_name_tool difference between -change and -id

Tags: xcode, macos, otool, install-name-tool

I have been struggling with this concept for a while and I cannot really understand what the difference is between `-change` and `-id`.The man page states

```
 -id name
              Changes  the  shared  library identification name of a dynamic shared library to name.  If the Mach-O binary is not a dynamic
              shared library and the -id option is specified it is ignored.

-change old new
              Changes  the dependent shared library install name old to new in the specified Mach-O binary.  More than one of these options
              can be specified.  If the Mach-O binary does not contain the old install name in a specified -change  option  the  option  is
              ignored.
```

So far I have experimented with `-change`. Suppose I have the following structure

```
Test.App
|_Contents
    |_MacOS
    |   |_test -----> item A
    |_Library
        |_test_library.dylib     --->item B
        |_another_library.dylib  --->item C
```

Now suppose I ran the following on itemB

```
$ otool -L test_library.dylib
   test_library.dylib
   /some/path/another_library.dylib  -->item D
```

The above result indicates that `test_library.dylib` depends on `another_library.dylib` now if I needed to change the location of `another_library.dylib` I would do this

```
install_name_tool -change /some/path/another_library.dylib some/new/path/another_library.dylib  test_library.dylib
```

this would change the location of item D. My question is what does `install-name_tool -id` do and when do I use that ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Install Name

The term *install name* refers to the exact path of the `.dylib` file in the end-user system so the runtime linker can find and load the dynamic library.

The name can be either:

- Absolute, which is the case for system libraries.  These are in the same place on both the end-user's and developer's system.
- Relative, which is the case of libraries bundled with apps.  On the end-user's system the `.dylib` will be embedded in the app bundle and on the developer system they will be either pre-built in `/usr/local`, `/opt/local` or somewhere else, or they will be built from source as part of the app build.

The latter is the main problem as when the `.dylib` is built, its *install name* is stamped into the `.dylib` by the linker and that's where it's expected to be found and loaded from at runtime. Obviously this won't work on the end-user system as that path only exists on the developer's system, so the solution is to use `install_name_tool` to modify the *install name* of the libraries, and executables that reference those libraries, when putting the app bundle together.

## Placeholders

As executables/app bundles can be installed in different places on the end-user system you can use a placeholder system to abstract the *install name* location:

- `@executable_path`: The full path of the main executable.
- `@loader_path`: The full path of the referencing executable or `.dylib`.
- `@rpath`: The RPATH set in the main executable.  This can also be changed using `install_name_tool`.

So for example in a macOS app bundle the executable would be in `TheApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TheApp` and libraries would be in `TheApp.app/Contents/Frameworks` so you would want to reference the libraries using the path `@executable_path/../Frameworks/Library.dylib`.

It's better to set RPATH of the main executable to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` however, and refer to the libraries using `@rpath/Library.dylib`.

## install_name_tool

`install_name_tool` has two main options:

`-id`: This sets the *install name* of the `.dylib` file itself and will be used as the prototype *install name* from that point forward when something links with the `.dylib`.  You could "correct" the *install name* immediately after building the `.dylib`, however that's an unusual workflow as how would a library know about the environment of whatever is using it?

`-change`: This changes the *install name* of a `.dylib` within a referencing executable (or dylib).

What happens when the `-id` name doesn't match the `.dylib`s location on disk? Nothing. The `-change` option is the important one to get right as once the runtime linker has found the `.dylib` then that's mission accomplished.

Why have an `-id` name at all?  Surely if the linker is told to look for libraries in `dirA`, `dirB`, `dirC` (using `-L` for example) and it finds the library it's looking for then why does the library itself have to have its `-id` stamped into it?  No idea; it's probably some archaic nonsense.

## xcodedevtools

You would obviously script all this fixing-up as part of the build process, wouldn't you, and I've done that and published it [here](https://github.com/trojanfoe/xcodedevtools/blob/master/copy_dylibs.py) . See the [`README.md`](https://github.com/trojanfoe/xcodedevtools/blob/master/README.md) for details of how to configure it within Xcode.

Comment: Are you saying that we use -id when we are chnaging things on the main executable inside /Contents/MacOS/  ?

Comment: @MistyD No, you'd use `-change` for that.

Comment: So I am still confused as when to use -change ? Do you have any article that might explain this

Comment: @MistyD No, I'm sorry I don't.

Comment: @MistyD A bit late, but I've decided to redo my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`install_name_tool -id` is used for change the `install name` of `dylib`, you can use the `otool -D` see a dylib `install name` in the terminal, it will show the default value for you, the `/some/path/another_library.dylib` is the default `install name` of `another_library.dylib`, of course, you can change it use `install_name_tool -id` in the terminal, just use like this in terminal

```
install_name_tool -id /some/path/another_library_newname.dylib /some/path/another_library.dylib
```

now,you use the `otool -D /some/path/another_library.dylib`, you will find the `install name` is `/some/path/another_library_newname.dylib`

here is my example in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg7Gu.png)

Answer (score 3):

`id` is used at link time and `install name` is used at runtime. They are all information provided for the linker to **locate** the dylib. I followed this [tutorial](http://matthew-brett.github.io/docosx/mac_runtime_link.html#the-install-name).

Let me show an example,

```sh
$ cat a.cc
#include <iostream>
void a() { std::cout << "a()" << std::endl; }
$ clang++ -c a.cc
```

```sh
$ clang++ -o liba.dylib -dynamiclib a.o
$ otool -L liba.dylib
liba.dylib:
        liba.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

As you can see, the first line is the `id`. Let's link with libb.dylib,

```sh
$ cat b.cc
#include <iostream>
void a();
void b() { std::cout << "b()" << std::endl; a(); }
$ clang++ -c b.cc
$ clang++ -o libb.dylib -dynamiclib b.o -L. -la
$ otool -L libb.dylib
libb.dylib:
        libb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        liba.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

Just notice the second line, the `id` for liba.dylib is used here. Let's change the id to `foo/liba.dylib` and link again,

```sh
$ install_name_tool -id foo/liba.dylib liba.dylib
$ otool -D liba.dylib
liba.dylib:
foo/liba.dylib
liba.dylib:
        foo/liba.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

So you see the `-D` and `-L` all outputs the current `id` as `foo/liba.dylib`.

Let's link again with liba.dylib again,

```sh
$ clang++ -o libb.dylib -dynamiclib b.o -L. -la
$ otool -L libb.dylib
libb.dylib:
        libb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        foo/liba.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

See the difference? The run time location to find liba.dylib is changed to `foo/liba.dylib` at the **second** line.

Basically, it tells libb.dylib to find liba.dylib from `current_dir/foo`